# Как в grep найти количество повторений символа по его коду?

Tags: linux, grep

Мне необходимо в командной строке с помощью команды grep найти сколько раз данный символ встречается в файле.

`grep -с '\u0031' "./1.txt"` не работает.

Comment: ну, например: `$ grep -c "$(echo -e '\x31')" ...` (можно использовать и не программу echo, а возможности совремменных навороченных оболочек, но для пущей переносимости лучше пусть так). ах, ну да, можно же и перловый синтаксис взять: `$ grep -Pc '\x31' ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `bash`'e можно как-то так:

```
grep -Fo $'\u0031' "./1.txt" | wc -l
```

Comment: и zsh тоже так умеет. это просто к слову: я zsh никогда не пользовался из-за его дырявости.

Answer (score 1):

ещё вариации (помимо приведённой уже возможности современных навороченных оболочек типа bash/zsh):

```
$ grep -Pc '\x{0031}' файл
$ grep -Pc '\x31' файл
$ grep -c "$(echo -e '\x31')" файл
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
grep -o $'\u0031' test_grep | uniq -c
```